# Occasional Authorization Errors with IIS, Azure Files and DFS

Tags: iis, dfs, virtual-directory

We'd had some IIS apps configured to run as a local user with admin privs per the standard recommended practice: [David So's Blog - IIS and Azure Files](https://blogs.iis.net/davidso/azurefile). Some sites' app pools were running as domain accounts and some were AF local accounts. For each site, some virtual directories pointed to AF paths with the AF user and some pointed to a DFS share with the domain user. When we changed the last domain account to run as the AF user, we started getting mysterious authentication errors saying username and password were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A senior member of our team proposed that there is some machine level connection to the DFS that must be tended to. Our work around was to keep a fake site configured to run as the domain user and keep it alive with occasional http requests from another machine. The auth problem, which used to show up daily, has not returned for over a week. I don't know precisely why this is true, but it was so painful that I wanted to document it here in case it helps. Hopefully others who know what they're doing can provide more precise answers.